# Has the loot system been rebalanced in the pre-sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

So, I picked up the pre-sequel, and am about level 15. I've already found an orange shield from a badass enemy, and seen three in the Marcus Machines. They do however seem nerfed compared to the kind of legendary loot you'd get in Borderlands 2. Did 2k Australia rebalance the loot system? I'm definitely seeing more white/green than blue/purple/orange, but higher level loot seems more common than previous iterations.

Also, does "**W**hen **G**randma **B**urps, **P**atrick **O**beys" still apply, or are there other classes of loot?